# Skip notifications on filtered messages

Tags: gmail, inbox-by-gmail

I'm trying out the Google Inbox service, and I'm not sure it can do what I want it to do.

With regular Gmail, I have lots of message filters, bringing messages into "Later" tags, skipping the inbox, but leaving the messages unread - I get to them 5 or 6 times a day, but they're not important enough to read immediately. I don't get notifications in the browser or in my phone, but the folders show in bold, with an unread message count - this is the behavior I want, so I can quickly glance and determine if I have any "Later" messages to read.

In Inbox, leaving those filters on, the messages still go into the appropriate locations in the "Skip the Inbox" section, but it doesn't show an unread count, so I have to keep opening the folder looking for unread messages. If I remove the "Skip the Inbox" part of the rule, I get notified on my phone with every new message, even if they are part of a bundle.

Is there any way to either simply get an unread message count on these other folders, or leave messages in the inbox, and filter which notifications I actually receive on my phone?